# EC2 capped HTTPS upload

Tags: amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elb

I have an application on 2 EC2 instances sitting behind an ELB.
The ELB does HTTPS termination and then speaks HTTP to the instances.

When uploading via HTTPS the transfer seems to be capped at ~ 10 Mbps per file (ex. 2 files will upload at 20 Mbps, 3 at 30 Mbps and so on) whereas if I transfer via HTTP I can easily saturate a 100 Mbps upload link with a single file.

I tried moving the HTTPS termination to the instances (nginx) and my tests gave the same results.

I have tried from different clients (OS and browser) and different uplink networks. The results are always the same.

I really have no clue as to where to start troubleshooting this issue, so any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess ELB is designed for horizontal scalability, not necessarily for high single-stream throughput. That's what you observed as well - many concurrent streams are all performing well but each single one is capped at some max throughput.

If you want to speed up upload to AWS have a look at **[S3 Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html)** - that will probably be much faster and your files will be saved directly to a S3 bucket from where they can be processed further by your application. You can even get *SNS notifications* whenever a new file upload is completed so that you can kick off is processing immediately.

Depends on your usecase of course but uploading large files through ELB and Nginx doesn't seem like you're using the best available services for the purpose. These would be more fit for handling a large number of concurrent users, not a small number of heavy users.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I understand what you're saying @MLu but why would this be true only in HTTPS?

Comment: @jeremyjr Good question. I'm only speculating here but it may well be that AWS offloads HTTPS encryption to some HW accelerators that have limited bandwidth per stream? It may be a question for AWS Support...

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was an HTTP2 problem.

Citing the AWS Support rep:

> Although ALB supports data transfer using HTTP 2.0 protocol while connecting over HTTPS, the upload a file could be slower than HTTP1.1 if the client uses a single stream in the connection to upload it.
>
> In a general use, the HTTP2 introduces an additional layer of flow control on top of TCP flow control that is intended to allow applications to control throughput per HTTP2.0 stream, allowing the applications to ensure equal treatment to all streams on a connection or conversely to prioritize one or some streams above others.
>
> In an ALB, the HTTP/2.0 window update for a single stream is capped to 64K. The clients have to advertise WINDOW_UPDATE frame consistently for every 64KB otherwise, if slow, it will negatively affect the throughput when only one stream is utilized for doing larger uploads on relatively high latency networks as compared to HTTP/1.1 or lower versions which lack this feature.
>
> Generally the Clients over the internet like Chrome, Firefox, an others are designed to advertise this in a slow fashion considering that the server is having a bigger cap on the frame, experiencing latency.

We disabled HTTP2 and uploads are now lightning fast!