Apache on Windows slow file upload via browser
I'm trying to troubleshoot poor performance when uploading large files to a Windows server running Apache.
Server:
Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
AMD EPYC 7763 64-Core Processor 2.44 GHz
32 GB RAM
Download speed (Mbps): 1737.12
Upload speed (Mbps): 2284.35

Local:
Download speed (Mbps): 269.31
Upload speed (Mbps): 48.37

Apache/PHP:
Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) PHP/8.2.16 OpenSSL/3.1.5 configured

File:
MP4 format
886 MB

I've tested the benchmark by uploading via WeTransfer and it took 2m 45 sec.
The issue I am facing is that when attempting to transfer the file, either using plupload with chunking (50MB) or a simple HTML multiform; via a web browser it takes around 4m 30sec.
I then tested a command shell cURL script to POST the same file to the same server (both over http and https) and the transfer took 2m 32sec.
Can anyone explain to me why the performance via cURL is so much better that the browser; and if possible, how can I configure Apache to perform closer to the cURL transfer?
Thanks in advance,
Baz
Edit 1
OK, I think the problem kicks in when using a PHP web form over SSL.
I've monitored the server ethernet (Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter) performance during transfers.
PHP web form HTTP  = 2:30m @48-50 Mbps
PHP web form HTTPS = 4:30m @30 Mbps

I'm still unsure why curl behaves the same either over HTTP or HTTPS or how to tackle the PHP/SSL issue.
Edit 2
After some additional troubleshooting, it appears the issue is when http2 (h2) protocol is used.
Testing https file transfer using http/1.1 performs the same as http.
However, when defining http2 (h2), the performance is degraded.
I suspect this is down to receive flow control or similar.
Can anyone suggest any possible fixes for Windows Server 2019?

How can the server configuration affect the browsers performance for a file transfer?

@vidarlo I don't know, I'm only thinking logically. I'm a bit clueless when it comes to server stuff, I'm more of a developer. The same browser works great with WeTransfer, and my server is capable of speedy uploads (with cURL). I'm asking "if" its possible to configure Apache....

Profile the components to figure out where the bottleneck is. curl talks to the web server in the same way the browser does, so it's very unlikely that the webserver configuration would affect one and not the other.

@vidarlo Thanks man. Are there any open source tools to assist in this task? The only components I can think of are the browser and PHP.

@vidarlo please see my edit, just wondering if this is the correct forum for PHP/SSL troubleshooting or if it's best placed at stackoverflow?

Issue was down to enabled HTTP2 protocol.
Switching back to HTTP/1.1 solved the upload speeds (which were only evident with larger files).
Answered here: https://serverfault.com/a/932702/345337
Edit: 2024-11-19 SOLUTION!
Our IT support provider came up with a solution.
We needed to increase the [H2WindowSize directive] from 65535 to 5120001.
<IfModule http2_module>
    ProtocolsHonorOrder On
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
    # Set H2WindowSize accordingly 128000/512000/1024000
    H2WindowSize    512000
</IfModule>

Now the upload performance is super fast and much more comparable to HTTP/1.1; it can also be tweaked to suit the server/network speeds.
This is specifically for Apache on Windows OS.
I hope this helps others facing the same problem on Windows.
